# data structure project using Avl tree

Tags: c++, data-structures

hello everybody Can anyone help me in choosing a project for data structure course final project in c++ my teacher told me to do it using avl tree I just want to ask which project will be useful to do it any management system,like library,banking,etc,which proposal will be best plesae help me I will be very thankful to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avl trees are used, basically when you want to store information and search for it using quickly from a key.

With this premise, you can use them, for example, in a relational database key search, a dictionary word search, a compiler analizer, etc.